# How to get url parameters in mongodb serverless https endpoint function?

Tags: mongodb

my function :=

```
exports = function({ query, headers, body}, response) {
const result = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas")
.db("hrtools")
.collection("users")
.find({}).toArray();

return result;
};
```

Now i want to get parameter sent in url to findOne with _id sent in url params

how to get url params to pass in findOne ?